# How to simplify the query executed rows in cake php

Tags: cakephp

In my cakephp i need to retrieve datas from database.

how can i display the table result in neat format.

Controller:

```
  function MarketingTaskmanagement(){
    $data['list'] = $this->TravancoAdmin->get_task_all();
    $this->set($data); 
    $this->render('Marketing/taskmanagement');
  }
```

Model:

```
function get_task_all(){

               $users = $this->query('select * from tbl_tasks');

        if($users){
            return $users;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

View:

But it displays values as so many arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [tbl_tasks] => Array ( [task_ids_mm] => 1 [task_title_mm] => ghjg [task_description_mm] => gjg [task_from_mm] => 09/04/2012 [task_to_mm] => 09/27/2012 ) ) [1] => Array ( [tbl_tasks] => Array ( [task_ids_mm] => 2 [task_title_mm] => hf [task_description_mm] => hfgh [task_from_mm] => 09/03/2012 [task_to_mm] => 09/27/2012 ) ) [2] => Array ( [tbl_tasks] => Array ( [task_ids_mm] => 3 [task_title_mm] => hf [task_description_mm] => hfgh [task_from_mm] => 09/03/2012 [task_to_mm] => 09/27/2012 ) ) [3] => Array ( [tbl_tasks] => Array ( [task_ids_mm] => 4 [task_title_mm] => hfh [task_description_mm] => fgh [task_from_mm] => 09/03/2012 [task_to_mm] => 09/20/2012 ) ) [4] => Array ( [tbl_tasks] => Array ( [task_ids_mm] => 5 [task_title_mm] => h [task_description_mm] => h [task_from_mm] => 09/04/2012 [task_to_mm] => 09/28/2012 ) ) [5] => Array ( [tbl_tasks] => Array ( [task_ids_mm] => 6 [task_title_mm] => hjk [task_description_mm] => hk [task_from_mm] => 09/05/2012 [task_to_mm] => 09/22/2012 ) ) [6] => Array ( [tbl_tasks] => Array ( [task_ids_mm] => 7 [task_title_mm] => v [task_description_mm] => v [task_from_mm] => 09/03/2012 [task_to_mm] => 09/28/2012 ) ) [7] => Array ( [tbl_tasks] => Array ( [task_ids_mm] => 8 [task_title_mm] => d [task_description_mm] => d [task_from_mm] => 09/03/2012 [task_to_mm] => 09/28/2012 ) ) [8] => Array ( [tbl_tasks] => Array ( [task_ids_mm] => 9 [task_title_mm] => f [task_description_mm] => d [task_from_mm] => 09/04/2012 [task_to_mm] => 09/27/2012 ) ) [9] => Array ( [tbl_tasks] => Array ( [task_ids_mm] => 10 [task_title_mm] => b [task_description_mm] => b [task_from_mm] => 09/05/2012 [task_to_mm] => 09/27/2012 ) ) )
```

In codeigniter there have something like this:

```
$users = $this->query('select * from tbl_tasks')->result();
```

Then it displays the correct array without any complication .

So how can i do this in cakephp?

And i need to display the all `task_title_mm` values from the table result in view page.

How can i do this?

Comment: typically you should use `$this->set('some_var', $data);`, then you can access this data - `foreach($some_var as $foo) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you expanded your question I'll elaborate a bit on the anwser.

It is a good practice to not use `$this->query()` where a native cake search would work.

if you don't have a model file for your `tbl_tasks` create one:

```
<?php
class Task extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Task';
    var $displayField = 'task_title_mm';
    var $useTable = 'tbl_tasks';
}
```

Load it inside your `get_task_all()` function. You can load a model dinamically inside another.

```
function get_task_all(){
    //load the Task model on the fly if it isnt associated with this one
    //loadModel won't work because we're inside a model. 
    //App:import might work, dunno.
    $this->Task = ClassRegistry::init('Task');

    $users = $this->Task->find('list');

    return $users ? $users : 1;
}
```

`find('list')` works if you declare `'task_title_mm'` as displayField otherwise you can use `$this->Task->find('all', array('fields' => array('task_title_mm')));`, but the result will be prefixed with `['Task']`;

Answer (score 1):

Use the "find" method.

```
$this->ModelName->find('all');
```

or

```
$this->ModelName->find('list');
```

If you need less information from query, put:

```
$this->ModelName->recursive = -1;
```

before find method.

Comment: Explore using the `Containable` behavior, it will make your life easier. Better than using recursive.

Answer (score 0):

function get_task_all(){ 
               $users = $this->query('select * from tbl_tasks') ....

Hey hey hey! Stop right there! That just gave me a heart attack.

Zero. Read the cookbook! No seriously, Stop! before you go any further I would suggest going through the cookbook atleast once. Do things the right way from the beginning is the way to go.

1. Use proper methods that cake has provided you to get the job done. SQL queries can get the job done just fine, but trust me using cake's inbuilt methods will benefit you long term and make your life much easier.
2. As per your query on how to display the data in table format, use cake bake: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1522/Code-Generation-with-Bake . The cake bake utility will generate the basic scaffold for your application controllers, models, views included. The default view templates of cake are really useful and has almost all the functionality built in, pagination etc.

Want a paginated result? No problem use paginate!

```
function index() {
    $this->ModelAlias->recursive = -1;
    $this->set('list', $this->paginate());
}
```

And voila! you have your paginated data inside $list readily available in your view. And if you have your views baked everything is nicely displayed in a table as you needed.

Don't want to fetch everything? Insert conditions into paginate like this:

```
function index() {
    $this->ModelAlias->recursive = -1;
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array('ModelAlias.tasks' => 'incomplete')
    );
    $this->set('list', $this->paginate());
}
```

Not only this you can include virtually any otherkey like 'fields', 'order', 'limit' that cake supports.

Once you start using cake's functions things start to get really awesome. For fetching related data you can use cake 'containable' behavior. This is just one thing of hundreds that cake does really well. I can't outline everything here, I insist please have a go at the cookbook http://book.cakephp.org